# Not able to run a Taurus performance test on an existing API

Tags: testing, performance-testing, blazemeter, taurus

After installing `Taurus` on Win 10 machine and creating a new file for performance testing my API:

**perf-test-config.yml**

```
execution:
- concurrency: 100
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 2m
  scenario: helloworld-api-perf-test

scenarios:
  quick-test:
    requests:
    - https://helloworld-api.cfapps.io
```

I get following error in log:

**Error Log:**

```
> bzt perf-test-config.yml
15:32:18 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.11.0
15:32:18 INFO: Starting with configs: ['perf-test-config.yml']
15:32:18 INFO: Configuring...
15:32:18 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Users\chandeln\MY-WORK\helloworld-api\2018-03-29_15-32-18.609453
15:32:18 WARNING: at path 'execution.0.scenario': scenario 'helloworld-api-perf-test' is used but isn't defined
15:32:18 INFO: Preparing...
15:32:19 WARNING: Could not find location at path: helloworld-api-perf-test
15:32:19 ERROR: Config Error: Scenario 'helloworld-api-perf-test' not found in scenarios: dict_keys(['quick-test'])
15:32:19 INFO: Post-processing...
15:32:19 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\Users\chandeln\MY-WORK\helloworld-api\2018-03-29_15-32-18.609453
15:32:19 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in [taurus User Manual](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/) `scenario` in execution should be also under `scenarios` for example:

```
execution:
- concurrency: 100
  ramp-up: 1m
  hold-for: 2m
  scenario: helloworld-api-perf-test

scenarios:
  helloworld-api-perf-test:
    requests:
    - https://helloworld-api.cfapps.io
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only `quick-test` under "scenarios" dictionary and in "execution" block you're trying to call something named `helloworld-api-perf-test`

So the options are in:

1. Change `scenario: helloworld-api-perf-test` to `scenario: quick-test`
2. Change `quick-test:` to `helloworld-api-perf-test:`

More information:

1. [Taurus Configuration Syntax](http://gettaurus.org/docs/ConfigSyntax/)
2. [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)